# Apollo's MockedProvider doesn't provide a client for components wrapped in withApollo

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, apollo

While testing a component wrapped in withApollo, I'm using Apollo's MockedProvider as specified in Apollo's documentation, but when enzyme tries to render that component, the renderer doesn't find the `client` that MockedProvider should have provided.

I have a component that uses `useQuery` in an Apollo context.

```js
export const QUERY = gql`{ value }`
export const Component = withApollo(({ client ) => {
    const { data } = useQuery(QUERY)
    return <p>{ data }</p>
})
```

So I want to test it:

```js
describe('Component', () => {
    const mocks = [{
        request: { query: QUERY },
        result: { data: 42 }
    }]
    const WrappingComponent = ({ children }) => <MockedProvider mocks={ mocks } addTypename={ false }>
        { children }
    </MockedProvider>
    WrappingComponent.propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.any
    }
    const component = shallow(<Component />, { wrappingComponent: WrappingComponent })

    it('matches the snapshot', () => {
        expect(enzymeToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
}
```

In this case, the snapshot turns out to be

```js
exports[`CruxProductSetup matches the snapshot 1`] = `
<ApolloConsumer>
  <Component />
</ApolloConsumer>
`;
```

Not my component, so I do a trick and try to get inside:

```js
    const component = shallow(shallow(<Component />, { wrappingComponent: WrappingComponent }).get(0))
```

And the snapshot is:

```js
exports[`Component matches the snapshot 1`] = `
<ContextConsumer>
  <Component />
</ContextConsumer>
`;
```

Still not useful. My component hasn't been rendered yet. I do the trick once more:

```js
const component = shallow(shallow(shallow(<Component />, { wrappingComponent: WrappingComponent }).get(0)).get(0))
```

And before the snapshot is taken, enzyme throws this error:

```
 FAIL  Component/__tests__/index.js
  Component
    ✕ encountered a declaration exception (75ms)

  ● Component › encountered a declaration exception

    Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context of ApolloConsumer. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>.

      85 |     })
      86 |
    > 87 |     const component = shallow(shallow(shallow(<Component />, { wrappingComponent: WrappingComponent }).get(0)).get(0))
      88 |     // const component = shallow(shallow(shallow(<Component />, { wrappingComponent: WrappingComponent }).get(0)).get(0))
      89 |     // const component = shallow(shallow(shallow(<CruxProductSetup summaryPanel={ null } />, { wrappingComponent: WrappingComponent }).get(0)).get(0))
      90 |

      at new InvariantError (node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.esm.js:12:28)
      at invariant (node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.esm.js:24:15)
      at Object.children (node_modules/@apollo/react-common/lib/react-common.cjs.js:55:132)
      at Object.type (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:612:30)
      at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:104:34)
      at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:615:53
      at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/src/Utils.js:99:18)
      at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:615:18)
      at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:411:22)
      at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
      at Suite.<anonymous> (Component/__tests__/index.js:87:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (Component/__tests__/index.js:61:1)
```

"`Could not find "client" in the context of ApolloConsumer. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>`"? I thought that was what `MockedProvider` was doing.

My dependencies:

```
@apollo/react-testing: 3.1.3
enzyme: 3.11.0
graphql-tag: 2.10.1
jest: 22.4.4
react: 16.12.0
react-apollo: 3.1.3
```

Comment: Having this exact issue... For some reason I can't get the tests to work with shallow mounting, and deep mounting throws frustrating "act" related errors which can't be fixed.

Comment: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2369

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same version of @apollo/react-testing as yours and instead of react-apollo, I'm using @apollo/react-hooks and I encountered the same error today.

Just upgrading @apollo/react-hooks and @apollo/react-testing to v4.0.0 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me! After upgrading to v4.0.0, I was able to `import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing'` and then pass that to my `renderHook` function as shown here:

`const { result } = renderHook(() => useProfileFunctions(props), { wrapper: MockedProvider })`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out having installed `react-apollo` and `@apollo/react-hooks` was causing it. Removed the `react-apollo dependecy`.