# how to use multiple versions of Apollo client in single project

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Im in the process on taking over an older React/Apollo/GraphQL project, which are currently not using hooks such as useQuery, useMutation etc.. So im trying to make an upgrade.

I've installed the package @apollo/react-hooks, and replaced ApolloProvider in my App.js

```
//import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'; //Old
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks'; //New

<ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>......</ApolloProvider>
```

This however result in an error when running the application:

index.mjs?8baf:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
at eval (index.mjs?8baf:1)
at Module../node_modules/graphql/index.mjs (vendors.aa829d69df1a68216354.js:7568)
at **webpack_require** (app.aa829d69df1a68216354.js:780)
at fn (app.aa829d69df1a68216354.js:148)
at eval (index.js:3)
at Object../node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/index.js

My package.json has the following packages related:

```
"react-apollo": "^2.0.1",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.1.12",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
"@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
"apollo-link": "^1.2.2",
"apollo-link-batch-http": "^1.2.2",
"apollo-link-context": "^1.0.8",
"apollo-link-error": "^1.0.9",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.4",
"apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.8",
"apollo-utilities": "^1.0.11"
```

If I try to use the ApolloProvider from 'react-apollo', I can run my application, but when adding :

```
import {useQuery} from '@apollo/react-hooks';
```

The application wont load.

I hope someone has experienced the same before who has a solution.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to go through the Apollo docs once again.

Here is the link for [Introduction to Apollo Client for React](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/).

Taken from [Apollo Docs for React](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#connect-your-client-to-react):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <div>
        <h2>My first Apollo app </h2>
      </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You need to import `ApolloProvider` from `@apollo/client` but not from `@apollo/react-hooks`.

And also try to install version 4 of everything related to apollo react. Otherwise, you might encounter numerous errors like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63564194/4859791)

---

**Edit:**

If you want to combine both versions as you are gradually refactoring the code, try to provide the `client` created using Apollo v4 directly to the hooks. This is the approach we are currently using in our work.

`useQuery` and `useMutation` has [options](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#options) object which can take `client` instance. So, try to create a new `client` instance using the new  Apollo v4 package, and instead of passing this new `client` to `ApolloProvider`, import the client in every component and provide it to the hooks explicitly using the `options` object. Once you complete refactoring to the hooks, you can wrap your components in `ApolloProvider` and remove the `client` instance in the `options` object(Even if you don't remove it, it works fine until you keep using the same `client`(Apollo v4) instance in `ApolloProvider` and `useQuery`'s and `useMutation`'s `options` object).

---

**Edit: 2**

The thing is you are currently using Apollo Client v2.6. But the newer version is Apollo Client v3.x. And the new version of `@apollo/react-hooks` obviously expects you to use the latest Apollo Client v3.x.

So, you need to maintain two apollo client files until you refactor your whole codebase to react hooks.

1. Using apollo-client^2 - To use with your existing code (which you already have)
2. Using @apollo/client^3 - To use with apollo hooks

When you do,

```
<ApolloProvider client={oldClientCreatedUsingv2}>
      <div>
        <h2>My first Apollo app </h2>
      </div>
</ApolloProvider>
```

The `useQuery` and `useMutation` hooks use the `client` provided in the `ApolloProvider`. But you can't use this for two `ApolloProvider`s versions obviously. It will be conflicting.

So, in the `ApolloProvider` provide your v2 apollo client instance so that your existing codebase is not disturbed. **In fact, you don't even have to modify anything here. Let it be how it is now.**

And in the `useQuery` and `useMutation`, provide the v3 apollo client instance(i.e., create a client using @apollo/client like [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#create-a-client)). **This is the only thing you have to do.**

Next, while making queries or mutations using hooks, provide the client created using v3 like this everywhere:

```
const {loading, error, data } = useQuery(YOUR_QUERY, { client: newClientCreatedUsingv3 });
```

`ApolloProvider` is only used to pass down the `client` so that we don't have to import it in every component and pass it to the hooks of `useQuery` and `useMutation` or HOC.

## If you explicitly provide a client while making a request, then it doesn't use the client provided in `ApolloProvider`.

Once you completely refactor your code into using react hooks, then you can change the `ApolloProvider` like this:

```
<ApolloProvider client={newClientCreatedUsingv3}>
      <div>
        <h2>My first Apollo app </h2>
      </div>
</ApolloProvider>
```

Now, you can remove the `client` option from every `useQuery` and `useMutation` to further clean up the code as from now onwards `useQuery` and `useMuation` will start using the `newClientCreatedUsingv3` instance provided in the `ApolloProvider`.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: But does that work with backwards compatibility? 
The reason is that I cant change all queries and mutations at one, but will do it over time, so I still need to have support for compose and the graphql HOC

Comment: @envy I've edited my answer for a suggestion on how we use old and new apollo packages at work. It should help you

Comment: Thx for the answer :) Although im not sure that you mean when you say "try to provide the client created using Apollo v4 directly to the hooks" ? 
As im hearing, you want two different apollo clients? Do you perhaps have an example on this, and how it's used in component, both class and function based?

Comment: @envy I've edited my answer with a more detailed explanation. I hope it should clarify your questions.

Comment: @envy maybe you need to modify your question to “how to use multiple versions of Apollo client in single project” so that other people can benefit from your use case in the future

Comment: Damn, still cant quite get it to work...  When trying to useQuery, im getting an error like: Object(...) is not a function... 

const {data, loading, error } = useQuery(groupsQuery, {
      client:apolloClientV3
    })

Comment: im using : 
import gql from 'graphql-tag' for gql queries

Comment: @envy I again set up a new project to check and it worked everything fine for me. Then I looked at the versions you are using. The problem is you are using `react^16.14`. React hooks are released in `react^16.8`. And also you can look at a similar issue [here](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/12). So obviously, you need to use `react^16.8` minimum to use the hooks feature.

Comment: @envy The best thing to do is, close this question as it works fine with the hooks and multiple versions of the apollo client and open a new question about how to use multiple react versions on the same project/page(It is actually possible to use 2 different versions of react in the same page). This might help you to develop new features using new react and refactor old react code to new react code gradually along with old apollo client code.

Comment: I've closed the question - unfortunately, still cant get it to work, even after setting React to 16.8 :( 

Which packages do you have installed? And are you using the ApolloProvider from v3 to wrap the whole app, are v2?

Comment: @envy my codebase is around 50k lines. The whole app is wrapped in v2 provider and newer code uses v3 client. I’m refactoring incrementally. And again, the error you said is because the react is not supporting hooks. How about you setup a new project with newer version of react and Apollo just to test everything works fine to single out the troubling part? And when you said you changed react to 16.8, how did you exactly do that? Did you change the version in package.json and forgot to npm install it?